# How to pass an array as an argument list

Tags: ruby, splat

Ruby's [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-start_with-3F) displays method signatures as:

```
start_with?([prefixes]+) → true or false
```

which looks like an array to me, but it is not. You can pass a single string or various string as arguments, like so:

```
"hello".start_with?("heaven", "hell")     #=> true
```

---

How do I pass an array as a list of arguments? The following does not work:

```
"hello".start_with?(["heaven", "hell"])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The brackets are a documentation convention for *optional* so the brackets in

> `start_with?([prefixes]+) → true or false`

are just saying that you can call `start_with?` with zero or more `prefixes`. This is a common convention in documentation, you'll see it the [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/on/) documentation, [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-extend) documentation, [MDN JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) documentation, and pretty much any other software documentation.

If you have an array of prefixes that you want to use with `start_with?`, then you can splat the array to unarrayify it thusly:

```
a = %w[heaven hell]
'hello'.start_with?(*a)           # true
a = %w[where is]
'pancakes house?'.start_with?(*a) # false
```

Comment: +1 Awesome, thanks, never heard of splat. Pretty new to ruby, thank you!